# Moving folders using PowerShell and CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, robocopy

We have identified via another PS script a shed load of user directories that are not active any more and wish to MOVE these user folders from the existing to an archive location.

I've got a far as identifying the users and have them outputted to a `.csv` file, e.g. the content is similar to below:

```
E:\Shares\Users$\AbassR
E:\Shares\Users$\AbbottJ
... and so on
```

I would like to use PowerShell and `robocopy` to avoid the long file name restriction and any other limitations Windows OS has.

I did find this script that I've modified:

```
GC -Path G:\Shares\ArchiveUsers$\userstomove.csv | ForEach-Object {
  robocopy $_ G:\Shares\ArchiveUsers$\Watford /E /Z /R:1 /W:1 /LOG+:G:\userscopied.txt /NP
}
```

It does copy (not move), but also it does not recreate the original folders in the destination.  It seems to only copy files from the folders shown in the `.csv` file and copies to root of the destination archive folder.

It would make my life so much easier if it could MOVE (perhaps with the robocopy `/mov` switch) the source folders identified in the `.csv` file to a folder with the same name in the destination archive location) alongside with all the other folders we had previously manually migrated.

Answer (score 2):

Using the parameter `/e` already makes `robocopy` copy directories recursively. However, `robocopy` copies the *content* of the source directories to the destination directory, not the entire directory, thus effectively merging/overwriting files from different users.

To have the source directories copied to individual destination directories you need to specify those individual directories as the destination. To move the source directories to the destination replace `/e` with `/move`.

```
$dst = 'G:\Shares\ArchiveUsers$\Watford'

... | ForEach-Object {
    $name = [IO.Path]::GetFileName($_)
    robocopy $_ "$dst\$name" /move /z /r:1 /w:1 /log+:G:\userscopied.txt /np
}
```

Comment: Is there an advantage not using the cmdlets? `Join-Path $dst (Split-Path $_ -Leaf)` I was on the way to a very similar answer.

Comment: No advantage. It's just a different way to the same end.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I assumed I needed to modify the suggested script as such                                                                                                             
$dst = 'G:\Shares\ArchiveUsers$\Watford'

GC -Path G:\Shares\ArchiveUsers$\userstomove.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $name = [IO.Path]::GetFileName($_)
    robocopy $_ "$dst\$name" /move /z /r:1 /w:1 /log+:G:\userscopied.txt /np
} This did work in that it now copies the folder, however the contents of the source folder were not copied/moved.

Comment: @Jason What does your log say about that?

Answer (score 0):

In the end this is the script that I ended up with, did the job.  However I did have subsequent problems of moving sub folders of users directories such as My Pictures that I wasn't the owner of.

```
GC -Path G:\Shares\ArchiveUsers$\userstomove.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $dst = 'G:\Shares\ArchiveUsers$\Watford'
    $name = [IO.Path]::GetFileName($_)
    robocopy $_ "$dst\$name" /move /e /z /r:1 /w:1 /TEE /log+:G:\Shares\ArchiveUsers$\userscopied.txt /np
   }
```

Thanks for all the input.